# Typescript unable to determine type

Tags: typescript

I have 2 cat objects with matching interface

Can someone explain to me why I can not set c1 to a number and c2 to a string?

Shouldn't it be able to infer the type in the function?

```
interface Cat {
    name: string;
    size:  string | number;
}

function getCatSize(cat : Cat)  {

    if ( isNaN(Number(cat.size)))  {
        return cat.size;
    } else { 
        return cat.size;
    }
}


  let cat1 : Cat = {
    name: "Cat1",
    size:  "Big"
  };

  let cat2 : Cat = {
    name: "Cat2",
    size:  10
  };


  var c1 : string = getCatSize(cat1);
  // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
  // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

  var c2 : number = getCatSize(cat2);
  // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCatSize` accepts `Cat`. So you can assign an object with a `size` property that is either `number` or `string` but the information about whether the function was called with the `number` or `string` version is not captured in any way. Also the function itself returns `number | string`, typescript can't implicitly follow the relation between the test on `size` and the returned value.

You can write a function that uses generic type parameters to capture the actual type with which the function was called and returns this type.

```
interface Cat<T extends string | number = string | number> {
    name: string;
    size: T;
}
function getCatSize<T extends string | number>(cat: Cat<T>): T {

    if (isNaN(Number(cat.size))) {
        return cat.size;
    } else {
        return cat.size;
    }
}


let cat1: Cat<string> = {
    name: "Cat1",
    size: "Big"
};

let cat2: Cat<number> = {
    name: "Cat2",
    size: 10
};


var c1: string = getCatSize(cat1);

var c2: number = getCatSize(cat2);
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzAHgCrIgD0hABMBnZUsKUAc2QB9kQBXAWwCNpkBeCq2hkzacoAPmQBvAFDJZTOKwgAuPtRA0A3DLmlgAL2XJsWgL5SYzEAjDAA9iGQ0IYdGADK+iDjyEIJcpRqdIwsHNCiABQIGCquOKIAlCq40tqywDDIEcCkAHJwuRG5wtBRGAB0ugYJNZJpcrJQzsxQDtFglZ5aDSZ4ADakKNINDU1gLW0VVRDdcmZmUlJ9zsjtAIyxGJiBtOK8w3IgCoYARK5rJwA09dMqJwBCwDQnUiZaSyvtAEybWKEiezqDSOijuri+VxunhUawADK93lIAG5wKCrDaqAS8JwuDAeAxlMBrBLvFFohA-IRhNHY5yufEQQlfElAA)